# RabbitMQ: how to delete exchanges in a batch?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have created a lot of error exchanges (using EasyNetQ), about 1400 items. The name of each exchange looks like `ErrorExchange_xxxxx`.

I want to delete them all.
Is there any script to delete the exchanges in a batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method exchangeDelete available with Channel API

You can write a method such as below which takes list of exchangeNames to be deleted :

**DELETE EXCHANGE**

```
public void deleteExcahnges(List<String> exchangeNames){}
       ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost(localhost);
       Connection  connection = factory.newConnection();
       Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
       for(String exchangeName : exchangeNames){

        channel.exchangeDelete(exchangeName);

       }
}
```

It would delete all the exchanges.

Note:-> I am using `amqp-client.jar` for connecting to RabbitMQ server

Comment: Many thanks. I used your method and all error items are removed. You saved me a lot of time. Thank you.